# How to use proxy in puppeteer and headless Chrome?

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, puppeteer

Please tell me how to properly use a proxy with a puppeteer and headless Chrome. My option does not work.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
  const argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ["--proxy-server =${argv.proxy}","--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"]});
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
  await page.setUserAgent(argv.agent);
  await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(20000);
  try{
  await page.goto(argv.page);

  const bodyHTML = await page.evaluate(() => new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document))
  body = bodyHTML.replace(/\r|\n/g, '');
  console.log(body);
}catch(e){
        console.log(e);
}
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 66):

You can find an example about proxy at [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/examples/proxy.js)

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    // Launch chromium using a proxy server on port 9876.
    // More on proxying:
    //    https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-settings
    args: [ '--proxy-server=127.0.0.1:9876' ]
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://google.com');
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Thanks its working. Need to ask how should i pass multiple proxy server in args and use it with multiple if conditon? If you can suggest

Comment: Should be set scheme, be like: `[ '--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:9876' ]`

Answer (score 27):

It's possible with [**puppeteer-page-proxy**](https://github.com/Cuadrix/puppeteer-page-proxy).
It supports setting a proxy for an entire page, or if you like, it can set a different proxy for each request. And yes, it works both in headless and headful Chrome.

First install it:

```
npm i puppeteer-page-proxy
```

Then require it:

```js
const useProxy = require('puppeteer-page-proxy');
```

**Using it is easy;**
Set proxy for an entire page:

```js
await useProxy(page, 'http://127.0.0.1:8000');
```

If you want a different proxy for each request,then you can simply do this:

```js
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on('request', req => {
    useProxy(req, 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9000');
});
```

Then if you want to be sure that your page's IP has changed, you can look it up;

```js
const data = await useProxy.lookup(page);
console.log(data.ip);
```

It supports **http**, **https**, **socks4** and **socks5** proxies, and it also supports authentication if that is needed:

```js
const proxy = 'http://login:pass@127.0.0.1:8000'
```

Repository:
https://github.com/Cuadrix/puppeteer-page-proxy

Comment: How can you use setRequestInterception to block images/css/fonts and useProxy at page-level ? If I use useProxy for each request it's too much slow

Comment: note: this library uses nodejs-got to download page, so it bypasses chrome downloader, it makes extra request to get a page. It won't work for many use cases.

Answer (score 23):

Do not use

```
"--proxy-server =${argv.proxy}"
```

This is a normal string instead of template literal use `` ` `` instead of `"`

```
`--proxy-server =${argv.proxy}`
```

Otherwise `argv.proxy` will not be replaced.

Check this string before you pass it to launch function to make sure it's correct
and you may want to visit http://api.ipify.org/ in that browser to make sure the proxy works normally

Comment: this should be the correct answer with respect to the question

Answer (score 7):

I see https://github.com/Cuadrix/puppeteer-page-proxy and https://github.com/gajus/puppeteer-proxy recommended above, and I want to emphasize that these two packages are technically not using Chrome instance to perform actual network request, here is what they are doing instead:

1. when the user code initiates network request of Puppeteer, e.g. calls `page.goto()`, the proxy package intercepts this outgoing HTTP request and pauses it
2. the proxy package passes the request to another network library (Got)
3. Got performs actual network request, through the proxy specified
4. Got now needs to pass all the network response data back to Puppeteer!  This means a bunch of *interesting* things the proxy package now needs to manage, like [copying cookie headers from raw HTTP set-cookie format to puppeteer format](https://github.com/Cuadrix/puppeteer-page-proxy/blob/master/src/core/proxy.js#L32)

While this might be a viable approach for a lot of cases, you need to understand that this changes your HTTP request TLS fingerprint so your HTTP request might get blocked by some websites, [particularly the ones which are using Cloudflare bot detection](https://pixeljets.com/blog/bypass-cloudflare/) (because the website now sees that your request originates from Node.js, not from Chrome).

## Alternative method of setting proxy in Puppeteer.

Launch args of Chrome are good if you want to use one proxy for all websites. What if you still want to have one Chrome instance use multiple proxies, but you don't want to use 2 packages mentioned above?

`createIncognitoBrowserContext` Puppeteer function to the rescue:

```js
// Create a new incognito browser context
const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext({ proxy: 'http://localhost:2022' });
// Create a new page inside context.
const page = await context.newPage();

// authenticate in proxy using basic browser auth
await page.authenticate({username:user, password:password});
// ... do stuff with page ...
await page.goto('https://example.com');
// Dispose context once it's no longer needed.
await context.close();
```

## proxy-chain package

If your proxy requires auth, and you don't like the `page.authenticate` call, the proxy might be set using [proxy-chain npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxy-chain).

[proxy-chain launches intermediate proxy on your localhost which allows to do some nice things](https://pixeljets.com/blog/how-to-set-proxy-in-puppeteer). Read more on technical details of proxy-chain package implementation: https://pixeljets.com/blog/how-to-set-proxy-in-puppeteer

Comment: Thanks so much for the great answers.  Note for windows user that a known bug in Chromium will block you here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1310057

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use different proxy for per page, try [this](https://github.com/xiyuan-fengyu/ppspider/blob/master/src/test/component/ProxyTest.ts), use https-proxy-agent or http-proxy-agent to proxy request for per page

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://github.com/gajus/puppeteer-proxy to set proxy either for entire page or for specific requests only, e.g.

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import {
  createPageProxy,
} from 'puppeteer-proxy';

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  const pageProxy = createPageProxy({
    page,
    proxyUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
  });

  await page.setRequestInterception(true);

  page.once('request', async (request) => {
    await pageProxy.proxyRequest(request);
  });

  await page.goto('https://example.com');
})();
```

To skip proxy simply call `request.continue()` conditionally.

Using [puppeteer-proxy](https://github.com/gajus/puppeteer-proxy) `Page` can have multiple proxies.

Answer (score 0):

You can find proxies list on [Private Proxy](https://app.privateproxy.me/) and use it with the code below

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const proxyChain = require('proxy-chain');

(async() => {
   // Proxies List from Private proxies
    const proxiesList = [
                'http://skrll:au4....',
                ' http://skrll:au4....',
                ' http://skrll:au4....',
                ' http://skrll:au4....',
                ' http://skrll:au4....',
     ];
    
    const oldProxyUrl = proxiesList[Math.floor(Math.random() * (proxiesList.length))];
    const newProxyUrl = await proxyChain.anonymizeProxy(oldProxyUrl);
    
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: true,
            ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
            args: [
              `--proxy-server=${newProxyUrl}`,
              `--ignore-certificate-errors`,
              `--no-sandbox`,
              `--disable-setuid-sandbox`
            ]
     });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.authenticate();

    // 
    // you code here
    //
     
    // close proxy chain
    await proxyChain.closeAnonymizedProxy(newProxyUrl, true);
})();
```

You can find the full post I wrote [here](https://lakson.medium.com/how-to-use-proxy-with-puppeteer-in-nodejs-d6d0af1680d).

Answer (score -3):

According to my experience, all above fail due to different reasons.
I find that applying proxy on the entire OS works each time. I get no proxy fails. This strategy works on both Windows and Linux.

This way, I get zero puppeteer bot failures. Bear in mind, I am spinning up 7000 bots per server. I am running this on 7 servers.

Comment: I think you should improve your question where it says "all above fail...", how often do they fail? the proxy setting is there because it works, be more specific of the situations that yours or others would fail.
Also, can you clarify what you mean by "applying proxy on the entire OS"? I'd like to know more, it sounds like you're saying you have 7 services that act as 7 proxies which is a small number of proxies.