# How to set proxy in nesk/puphpeteer?

Tags: php, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am using `puphpeteer` for my Web Automation program.
`nesk/puphpeteer` is a PHP version for `puppeteer`.
In `puppeteer` there is an example for proxy setting.
But in `nesk/puphpeteer` there isn't any document or example for it.
Does anybody know how to do it?

(This is not a duplicated question for [How to use proxy in puppeteer and headless Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52777757/how-to-use-proxy-in-puppeteer-and-headless-chrome))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is it.

```
$puphpeteer = new Puppeteer([
    'args' => ['--proxy-server=XXX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX']
]);
```

Hope this helps some other developers who face this problem again.
For more information please refer to this link:https://github.com/nesk/puphpeteer/issues/73